# Find the 'max' of a specific column with Pandas, then output that VALUE with a corresponding ITEM from the same row

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, lambda

I understand how to find the max value of the column 'CONTRCOST', but how do I take a corresponding value and input both pieces of information into a string like it is asking me to do?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Duplicate: /questions/35577092/pandas-find-max-value-in-column-and-print-its-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should give you what you want.  The `idxmax()` function returns the index of the row with the max value.  If there are more than one, it returns the first.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'id':0,'city':'Chicago','contrcost':1000000.00},
{'id':1,'city':'New York','contrcost':2000000.00},
{'id':2,'city':'Boston','contrcost':1000000.00},
{'id':3,'city':'Atlanta','contrcost':1000000.00},
{'id':4,'city':'Los Angeles','contrcost':2000000.00}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
max_index = df['contrcost'].idxmax()
print('City with the contract that has the greatest cost: {:s} (contract cost is ${:.2f})'
.format( df.iloc[max_index]['city'], df.iloc[max_index]['contrcost']))
```

Output: City with the contract that has the greatest cost: New York (contract cost is $2000000.00)

Comment: This works perfectly! Though I do have a question: how comes it returns the second half of the print statement on a different line? The portion after the colon.

Comment: It shouldn't.  I just cut and pasted exactly what is in the code box above into ipython and executed it and it printed a single line.  Off the top of my head, the only way it should end up on a second line is if there was a line feed '\n' after the colon or two print statements.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question.  If you are asking about the output when the code is executed that should be on one line, modulo wrapping if you window is narrow.  If you are asking about the code itself, and why the .format is on a second line, that is a coding style decision.  Very long lines are generally frowned upon.  The print line is 90 characters and many style guides would say that is too long (80 is a common limit).  If I had not put the .format on a separate line, it would have been 160 characters long and that definitely would have been too long.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Honestly, the original answer was exactly what I needed. It helped out a lot. The comment I made after was a mistake I had made, but just wanted to clarify your first answer was perfect. Thanks.